# How is the dimension of the vector space we represent $SO(3)$ on determined when discussing the spin of a particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, representation-theory, spin-statistics

Consider a single particle with Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3) \otimes V_\ell$ where $V$ is a vector space of dimension $2\ell + 1$ equipped with a projective unitary representation of $SO(3)$. Physically we say that the particle has spin $\ell$, for example for bosons $\ell$ is an integer and for fermions $\ell$ is an odd multiple of $1/2$.

The above math is fine but I am confused on the physics. For example, suppose we did not know that the spin of an electron is $\ell = 1/2$. How would we determine that the dimension of the vector space used to represent an electron must be 2? Why not 4, 6, 8...etc?

Comment: $2\times 1/2+1 =2$?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Sorry maybe the wording of my question isn't great. Since an electron is a Fermion we know that its spin must be a half-integer. But why not spin 3/2, 5/2...etc? Why must it be $1/2$? In other words, why must we represent SO(3) on a vector space of dimension 2?

Comment: Experirments...

Comment: @TobiasFünke Is this an entirely experimental result or can it be shown to be a mathematical consequence?

Comment: entirely experiment.  The Stern-Gerlach (or its one-electron version by Phipps, T.E.; Taylor, J.B. (1927). "The Magnetic Moment of the Hydrogen Atom". Physical Review. 29 (2): 309–320), show the beam splits only $2$ ways.  This also makes the spectroscopy data on the number of electrons per atomic state correct.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Thank you.